# jQuery tmpl adds double Quotes to image Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, templates, templating

I used PrototypeJS for years and loved the template features they had in their lib. I now changed to jQuery and i'm quite a beginner. I can't find the solution for my problem:

I get from an ajax request an json object containing an html image tag. It looks like:

```
<-- some data -->, "del":"<img src=\"img\/icon_delete.png\" class=\"firmenDelZData\" border=\"0\" height=\"17\" id=\"zdataid_13\">"}
```

When i take this data in jquery with the following calls (including the whole json object:

```
XHR = $.parseJSON( data );
alert( var.del );
```

i get an alert box showing the normal image tag without double quotes. But when i take this variable with the jquery template function as follows:

```
$.tmpl( "zdTemplate", { "del": firmenzd[i].del } ).appendTo("#zd");
```

The template engine inserts this image tag with double quotes and so the browser does not show the image, it shows the tag itself as text... how can i fix this?

```
 "<img src=\"img\/icon_delete.png\" class=\"fDelZData\" border=\"0\" height=\"17\" id=\"zdataid_13\">
```

I have another question: Why do i cannot find the $.tmpl function in the jQuery Plugin section? Is there another way to make such templating with jquery?

Thank you for your answers

M.

**SOLUTION**

After two more hours of search i found the great tag to insert HTML Code with the .tmpl function. I only had to put {{html del}} instead of ${del}.

So when defining the template i have to do it as follows:

```
`var zdTemplate = '<tr class="ptr zdEntry">' + 
                   '<td class="cellValue fontValue">{{html edit}}</td>' +     
                   '<td class="cellValue fontValue">{{html del}}</td>' + 
                 '</tr>';
$.template( "zdTemplate", zdTemplate );`
```

and the Templating goes as follows:

```
          ` $.tmpl( "zdTemplate", {
               "edit": firmenzd[i].edit,
               "del": firmenzd[i].del } ).appendTo("#data");`
```

Hope this helps someone else!

M.

PS: Found the solution for myself, im too new here to answer my own questions